# Coffeescript Image switcher?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

Can anyone give me an example of how to making an image switcher using coffeescript? I just have 3 images I want to fade in and out, but I couldn't find any tutorials for this.

Thanks

Comment: can someone please do my work for me too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of good jQuery plugins for this, e.g. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

With that plugin, you just put all of your `<img>` tags in a `<div>`—let's say it has the id `images`—and then you can simply write

```
$ ->
  $('#images').cycle fx: 'fade'
```